# making clickable text from php script

Tags: php, sql, clickable

I have a php script below

```
<?php include 'db_connector.php';
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT operation FROM contract");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['operation'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
  }
  ?>
```

That produces the following output
   Report on AP Events

```
Configure & Maintain Service

Configure & Monitor SNC

Configure & Monitor Service

Report ON SNC Events
```

Am using it in my code as follows

```
<div class="description"><a id="openpanel"><?php include 'showall_contract.php';?></a></div>
```

I would like to know, how can I make each list item (i.e Configure & Maintain Service) as a clickable link?

Comment: Look at the HTML anchor tag. [Here is the manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)

Comment: i think you want each link to produce different result. means different out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please echo the values inside anchor tag as

```
<?php

include 'db_connector.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT operation FROM contract");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<a href='your url' >" . $row['operation'] . "</a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href='whatever_your_url_is'>".$row['operation']."</a>";
```